# Save same object multiple times

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish

**Solution:** set Id = null and it will work.

This code works perfectly on Tomcat 7, but on Glassfish 4 it only saves only once. The code is aimed to merge the same instance of a object multiple times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>entities.Secao</class>
    <class>entities.Funcionario</class>
    <class>entities.Unidade</class>
    <class>entities.Patrimonio</class>
    <class>entities.Descricao</class>
    <class>entities.Classificacao</class>

    <validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/patrimonio" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
public void save() {
    int i = 0;
    EntityManager em = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

    while (i < 10) {
        em.merge(item);         
        i = i + 1;          
    }
    item = new Item();      
}
```

Comment: You're not clear on what step exactly this piece code fails. To start with, is the `salvar()` method invoked or not? If not, then you need to take a step back in the context and show in SSCCE flavor the JSF code which should invoke that method. If it is however properly invoked, then it's not a JSF problem at all and you need to focus on JPA part.

Comment: this is my persistence.xml https://github.com/erickdeoliveiraleal/sispatri/blob/master/src/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: @BalusC Yes, the method is invoked, but it only write one time to the database, while on Tomcat it does the 10.

Comment: Okay, then it's not a JSF problem. You'd better remove the JSF noise from the question to get better focus/attention from JPA experts. Coming back to the concrete problem, what exactly is the concrete functional requirement? What JPA implementation exactly are you using? Why exactly do you want to persist the same entity multiple times even if nothing has changed? I can imagine that some JPA implementations may for performance reasons not persist if the entity is not "dirty".

Comment: @BalusC This was a requirement of my client. Now I edited my question and added the persistence part. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the problem I had that time. Now, a long time later, I can save it with merge, only set id = null before save.

Answer (score 1):

`em.merge(item);` updates item in database, or inserts item, when not existing. So if there is no change, and flush is set to auto, only one merge is needed - because `item` doesn't changes between merges.

If you want to store this `item` multiple times, you have to `em.persist(item)`. If `@id` column isn't set to `generate`, you might have to update pk attribute - otherwise you will have `ConstraintViolationException`.

Implementation of JPA in application servers may be various, so you may observe different queries during runtime. Check your flushing policy and JTA settings. But, in general, no merge is needed when persisted item is not changed when detached from persistence context.

Comment: I changed to persist, but it continues to only save the first time.